# **Spotlight Search** does not see all the apps

Tags: macos, spotlight

It seems that recently my **Spotlight** indexing is broken. I noticed that it does not see/offer `R` and some other apps too. It does give me `RStudio` (and even R Kelly  ). I need constantly to do the following:

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
sudo mdutil -a -i on
```

After that, **Spotlight** is fine for a while and then it gets forgetful again. I am running the latest **Monterey** on my *MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)*.

Can you help? This is quite annoying, but more importantly, I worry that this can be a sign of some more serious issue. Elderly dementia?